# json unmarshal time that isn't in RFC 3339 format

Tags: json, go

What is the appropriate way to handle deserialization of different time formats in Go? The encoding/json package seems to be entirely rigid in only accepted RFC 3339. I can deserialize into a string, transform that into RFC 3339 and then unmarshal it but I don't really want to do that. Any better solutions?

Comment: A custom `UnmarshalJSON()` function is needed today, however, a proposal was made to do this easier. Read more and comment here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21990

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You will have to implement the [`json.Marshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) / [`json.Unmarshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interfaces on a custom type and use that instead, an [example](http://play.golang.org/p/UcE229WT98):

```
type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}

const ctLayout = "2006/01/02|15:04:05"

func (ct *CustomTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    s := strings.Trim(string(b), "\"")
    if s == "null" {
       ct.Time = time.Time{}
       return
    }
    ct.Time, err = time.Parse(ctLayout, s)
    return
}

func (ct *CustomTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
  if ct.Time.IsZero() {
    return []byte("null"), nil
  }
  return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", ct.Time.Format(ctLayout))), nil
}

var nilTime = (time.Time{}).UnixNano()
func (ct *CustomTime) IsSet() bool {
    return !ct.IsZero()
}

type Args struct {
    Time CustomTime
}

var data = `
    {"Time": "2014/08/01|11:27:18"}
`

func main() {
    a := Args{}
    fmt.Println(json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &a))
    fmt.Println(a.Time.String())
}
```

**edit**: added `CustomTime.IsSet()` to check it was actually set or not, for future reference.

Comment: For Marshalling the JSON you need to return the string quoted. So the MarshalJSON would be something like this: `return []byte(strconv.Quote(ct.Time.Format(ctLayout))), nil` (wrapped in `strconv.Quote`)

Comment: This returns a string with value null for null times. However, this does not cause the field to be omitted, if the CustomTime struct is the datatype of a struct element, which has "omitempty" tag added. Is there a way to fix that ? Also see: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11939

Comment: Marshelling method should be like `func (ct CustomTime) MarshalJSON()` You should be passing `ct` not pointer to it.

Comment: instead of nilTime you can just use ct.Time.IsZero()

Comment: Good post explaining this technique at https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/advanced-encoding-decoding/ under the "Custom types for specific fields" heading.

Comment: It will become problem, when you want to insert to sql database (using NamedExec). Example : tx.NamedExec(query, args). It would be error, because they don't know what is CustomTime. They only know time.Time

Comment: how do I create a new CustomTime object? CustomTime.Now() doesn't work.  Do I need to create a package CustomTime and create func Now in it?

Comment: `ct := CustomTime{time.Now()}`

Comment: Thanks for this. The UnmarshalJSON func was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 39):

The encoding/decoding is done by [`time.Time`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnmarshalJSON) itself, in the `MarshalJSON` and `UnamrshalJSON` methods. You could create your own `time.Time` type and override those functions to work with the json however you want.

```
type Time struct {
    time.Time
}

// returns time.Now() no matter what!
func (t *Time) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    // you can now parse b as thoroughly as you want

    *t = Time{time.Now()}
    return nil
}

type Config struct {
    T Time
}

func main() {
    c := Config{}

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"T": "bad-time"}`), &c)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c)
}
```

Comment: Whoa, I didn't even see this answer and I just posted mine, something funky is going on.

Answer (score 0):

There is very easy way to use temporary struct with `string` field instead of `time.Time` field with subsequent copying of result values:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Person struct {
    Name        string    `json:"name"`
    DateOfBirth time.Time `json:"date_of_birth"`
}

func main() {
    // here date_of_birth is in not standard RFC1123Z format
    raw := `{"name":"John Doe","date_of_birth":"Sat, 04 Nov 1923 22:11:08 +0100"}`
    // create temporary struct where DateOfBirth field will be string, not time.Time
    temp := struct {
        // use embedding
        Person
        // use string representation of DateOfBirth
        DateOfBirth string `json:"date_of_birth"`
    }{}
    // unmarshal into temp struct
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(raw), &temp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    // parse not standard RFC1123Z time format
    dateOfBirth, err := time.Parse(time.RFC1123Z, temp.DateOfBirth)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    // and build final result from temp
    result := Person{
        Name:        temp.Name,
        DateOfBirth: dateOfBirth,
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
}

// {John Doe 1923-11-04 22:11:08 +0100 CET}
```