# Golang decode 2 JSON items into 1 struct

Tags: json, parsing, go

i'm trying to decode 2 JSON items into the same struct, because the second JSON complet the first one, but it doesn't work (do nothing) have you got some ideas ?

```
func getUserClip(this *LibraryController, id string) (*Clip){
//Test Api
//Send Request to azure search
Data := Clip{}
if req := GetClipById("b373400a-bd7e-452a-af68-36992b0323a5"); req == nil {
    return nil
} else {
    str, err := req.String()
    if err != nil {
        beego.Debug("Error Json req.String: ", err)
    }
    //Uncode Json to string
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &Data); err != nil {
        beego.Debug("Error json", err)
    }
    for i := range Data.Value {
        if req = GetCliRedis(Data.Value[i].Id); err != nil {
            return nil
        } else {
            str, err := req.String()
            beego.Debug("JSON REDIS DEBUG: ", str)
            if err != nil {
                beego.Debug("Error Json req.String: ", err)
            }
            if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &Data); err != nil {
                beego.Debug("Error json", err)
            }
        }
        i++
    }
   }
  return &Data
}
```

and the struct

```
type Clip struct {
Value   []InfoClip `json:value`
}

type InfoClip struct {
Id                  string      `json:id`
CreatedAt           time.Time   `json:createdAt`
StartTimeCode       int         `json:startTimeCode`
EndTimeCode         int         `json:endTimeCode`
Metas               metas       `json:metas`
Tags                []string    `json:tags`
Categories          []string    `json:categories`
UserId              string      `json:userId`
SourceId            string      `json:sourceId`
ProviderName        string      `json:providerName`
ProviderReference   string      `json:providerReference`
PublicationStatus   string      `json:publicationStatus`
Name                string      `json:name`
FacebookPage        string      `json:facebookPage`
TwitterHandle       string      `json:twitterHandle`
PermaLinkUrl        string      `json:permalinkUrl`
Logo                string      `json:logo`
Link                string      `json:link`
Views               int         `json:views`
}

type metas struct {
Title               string      `json:title`
Tags                []string    `json:tags`
Categories          []string    `json:categories`
PermaLink           string      `json:permalink`
}
```

The JSON I receive is:

```
{  
   "clipId":"9b2ea9bb-e54b-4291-ba16-9211fa3c755f",
   "streamUrl":"https://<edited out>/asset-32e43a5d-1500-80c3-cc6b-f1e4fe2b5c44\/6c53fbf5-dbe9-4617-9692-78e8d76a7b6e_H264_500kbps_AAC_und_ch2_128kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=17ed71e8-5176-4432-8092-ee64928a55f6&sig=KHyToRlqvwQxWZXVvRYOkBOBOF0SuBLVmKiGp4joBpw%3D&st=2015-05-18T13%3A32%3A41Z&se=2057-05-07T13%3A32%3A41Z",
   "startTimecode":"6",
   "endTimecode":"16",
   "createdAt":"2015-05-19 13:31:32",
   "metas":"{\"title\":\"Zapping : Obama, Marine Le Pen et Michael Jackson\",\"tags\":[\"actualite\"],\"categories\":[\"actualite\"],\"permalink\":\"http:\/\/videos.lexpress.fr\/actualite\/zapping-obama-marine-le-pen-et-michael-jackson_910357.html\"}",
   "sourceId":"6c53fbf5-dbe9-4617-9692-78e8d76a7b6e",
   "providerName":"dailymotion",
   "providerReference":"x1xmnxq",
   "publicationStatus":"1",
   "userId":"b373400a-bd7e-452a-af68-36992b0323a5",
   "name":"LEXPRESS.fr",
   "facebookPage":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/LExpress",
   "twitterHandle":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/lexpress",
   "permalinkBaseURL":"https:\/\/tym.net\/fr\/{CLIP_ID}",
   "logo":"lexpress-120px.png",
   "link":"http:\/\/videos.lexpress.fr\/"
}
```

The Redis complet the azure search missing information :

here the struct :

```
type Clip struct {
Value   []SearchClip `json:value`
}

type SearchClip struct {
Id                  string `json:id`
CreatedAt           string`json:createdAt`
Tags                []string `json:tags`
Categories          []string `json:categories`
UserId              string `json:userId`
SourceId            string `json:sourceId`
Views               int `json:views`
}
```

this is the basic information and redis complet this

I don't want to merge 2 struct into a third one i think it's not the better process, i will do it if it's the last solution.

Comment: What did you try so far ? some code will help to more understand your problem :)

Comment: Just a heads up: People will complain about you not showing your progress, your specific problems and _code_. That being said, did you consider unmarshaling into two distinct structs and then merging them manually into one struct via embedding?

Comment: Yes i did but i need to merge them into a third one and it's not the lighter process i think

Comment: please provide the two JSON objects and your code to parse/combine them.

Comment: Thanks for providing the code. A few general notes: In your first snippet, you have a line `if req = GetCliRedis(Data.Value[i].Id); err != nil {` - you do not actually _set_ `err` in there, so checking if `err != nil` will use an `err` from before, and, as you always check if that's `!= nil`, `if` will always use the `else` branch. Additionally, but I've never used beego, I'm sure you can unmarshal the response directly, without reading it as a string first, but that's just a performance improvement...

Comment: @mrd0ll4r my first json its just for the view field and the seconde one is the rest

Comment: And each time its a JSON redis response and i don't know can i get them in one struct ..

Comment: Please provide your json so we can see what we're working with. You could embed the two structs in a third very easily (along the lines of what you don't want but it is very clean, no re-writing of fields in the new type). If you don't do that, you'll have to implement a custom unmarshal for your type. Personally I think that's more work than it's worth. The embed is super clean and simple.

Comment: As I can see, you have some errors in your `json:` tags, for example the `json:id` should be `json:clipId` and `json:permalinkUrl` should be `json:permalinkBaseURL` - as long as the tags are not correct, the `encoding/json` package will not know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I present to you this fully functional solution:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type Clip struct {
    Value []InfoClip `json:value`
}

type customTime struct {
    time.Time
}

const ctLayout = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"

func (ct *customTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    if b[0] == '"' && b[len(b)-1] == '"' {
        b = b[1 : len(b)-1]
    }
    ct.Time, err = time.Parse(ctLayout, string(b))
    return
}

type InfoClip struct {
    Id                string     `json:"clipId"`
    CreatedAt         customTime `json:"createdAt"`
    StartTimeCode     string     `json:"startTimeCode"` //if you want ints here, you'll have to decode manually, or fix the json beforehand
    EndTimeCode       string     `json:"endTimeCode"`   //same for this one
    Metas             metas      `json:"-"`
    MetasString       string     `json:"metas"`
    Tags              []string   `json:"tags"`
    Categories        []string   `json:"categories"`
    UserId            string     `json:"userId"`
    SourceId          string     `json:"sourceId"`
    ProviderName      string     `json:"providerName"`
    ProviderReference string     `json:"providerReference"`
    PublicationStatus string     `json:"publicationStatus"`
    Name              string     `json:"name"`
    FacebookPage      string     `json:"facebookPage"`
    TwitterHandle     string     `json:"twitterHandle"`
    PermaLinkUrl      string     `json:"permalinkBaseURL"`
    Logo              string     `json:"logo"`
    Link              string     `json:"link"`
    Views             int        `json:"views"`
}

type metas struct {
    Title      string   `json:"title"`
    Tags       []string `json:"tags"`
    Categories []string `json:"categories"`
    PermaLink  string   `json:"permalink"`
}

var jsonString = `{  
   "clipId":"9b2ea9bb-e54b-4291-ba16-9211fa3c755f",
   "streamUrl":"https://<edited out>/asset-32e43a5d-1500-80c3-cc6b-f1e4fe2b5c44\/6c53fbf5-dbe9-4617-9692-78e8d76a7b6e_H264_500kbps_AAC_und_ch2_128kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=17ed71e8-5176-4432-8092-ee64928a55f6&sig=KHyToRlqvwQxWZXVvRYOkBOBOF0SuBLVmKiGp4joBpw%3D&st=2015-05-18T13%3A32%3A41Z&se=2057-05-07T13%3A32%3A41Z",
   "startTimecode":"6",
   "endTimecode":"16",
   "createdAt":"2015-05-19 13:31:32",
   "metas":"{\"title\":\"Zapping : Obama, Marine Le Pen et Michael Jackson\",\"tags\":[\"actualite\"],\"categories\":[\"actualite\"],\"permalink\":\"http:\/\/videos.lexpress.fr\/actualite\/zapping-obama-marine-le-pen-et-michael-jackson_910357.html\"}",
   "sourceId":"6c53fbf5-dbe9-4617-9692-78e8d76a7b6e",
   "providerName":"dailymotion",
   "providerReference":"x1xmnxq",
   "publicationStatus":"1",
   "userId":"b373400a-bd7e-452a-af68-36992b0323a5",
   "name":"LEXPRESS.fr",
   "facebookPage":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/LExpress",
   "twitterHandle":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/lexpress",
   "permalinkBaseURL":"https:\/\/tym.net\/fr\/{CLIP_ID}",
   "logo":"lexpress-120px.png",
   "link":"http:\/\/videos.lexpress.fr\/"
}`

func main() {
    res := parseJson(jsonString)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n",res)
}

func parseJson(theJson string) InfoClip {
    toParseInto := struct {
        InfoClip
        MetasString string `json:"metas"`
    }{
        InfoClip:    InfoClip{},
        MetasString: ""}

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &toParseInto)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(toParseInto.MetasString), &toParseInto.InfoClip.Metas)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    return toParseInto.InfoClip
}
```

What are we doing in the `parseJson` function?

We create a new struct and assign that to the `toParseInto` variable. We design the struct in a way that it contains all of the fields from `InfoClip` via embedding, and We add a field to temporarily hold the JSON string `metas`.

We then unmarshal into that struct, which, after fixing the issues listed below, works fine.

After that, we unmarshal that *inner* JSON into the correct field in the embedded `InfoClip`.

We can now easily return that embedded `InfoClip` to get what we really wanted.

Now, all the issues I have identified in your original solution:

1. The time format in your JSON is not the standard time format to be used in JSON. That is defined in some RFC, but anyways: because of that, we have to use our own type `customTime` to parse that. It handles just like a normal `time.Time`, because that is embedded within.
2. **All** your json tags were wrong. All of them had missing quotes, and some were just not even correct.
3. `startTimeCode` and `endTimeCode` are strings in the JSON, not ints

Left to you to improve:

- Error handling: Don't just panic in the `parseJson` function, but rather return the error somehow
- If you want `startTimecode` and `endTimecode` to be available as ints, parse them manually. You can employ a "hack" similar to the one I used to parse the inner JSON.

One final note, not related to this answer but rather to your question: If you had provided both your code and the JSON with your original question, you would have had an answer in probably less than an hour. *Please*, *please* don't make this harder than it needs to be.

EDIT: I forgot to provide my sources, I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087960/json-unmarshal-time-that-isnt-in-rfc-3339-format) to parse your time format.

Comment: Thank you for helping me ! I have an error with json: unexpected end of json input

Comment: print your json before you decode it, inspect it manually, if you can't find the error, try something like [an online json formatter and validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)

Comment: The thing is this code work ouside the project but inside it can't decode []string

Comment: Well then, inside the project, print you JSON to some debug output and analyze it?

Answer (score 3):

For lack of activity I'm just gonna post the embedding option as a solution. It's probably the simplest way to do what you want.

```
type ClipInfoAndMeta struct {
      Metas
      InfoClip
}
```

Note I upper cased the name on `metas` not sure it's necessary but I believe it will be. The language feature being used here is called 'embedding' and it works a lot like composition except that the fields/methods for embedded types are more or less 'hoisted' to the containing types scope. IE with an instance of `ClipInfoAndMeta` you can directly access any exported field that is defined on `InfoClip`.

One oddity of your set up is that you'll have collisions on field names between the two types. Not sure how that would play out. With all this being said, it would be helpful to see the json string you're trying to Unmarshal from. As I've been writing this I realized that `metas` is just a subset of `InfoClip`. Which has confused me about what you are actually trying to do? I mean, if the data coming back is all in one object, it would mean `InfoClip` is sufficient for storing  all of it. If that is the case you have no reason for the other object... And if you want to trim down the fields which get passed to the display layer of your app you should just define a method on the `InfoClip` type like `func (i *InfoClip) GetMetas() Metas { return &Metas{ ... } }` then you can just deal with the one type everywhere and hand off the `Metas` to the display layer when it's needed.