# Unmarshal incorrectly formatted datetime

Tags: json, datetime, go, iso8601, rfc3339

## Background

I am learning Go and I'm trying to do some JSON unmarshaling of a datetime.

I have some JSON produced by a program I wrote in C, I am outputting what I thought was a valid [ISO8601](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/ISO_8601) / [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-4.2) timezone offset. I'm using [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) with the following format string:

```
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z
```

(Note that `%f` is not supported by [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) natively, I have a wrapper that replaces it with the nanoseconds).

This will then produce the following result:

```
2016-08-08T21:35:14.052975+0200
```

Unmarshaling this in Go however will not work:
https://play.golang.org/p/vzOXbzAwdW

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, "2016-08-08T21:35:14.052975+0200")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Output:

```
panic: parsing time "2016-08-08T21:35:14.052975+0200" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00": cannot parse "+0200" as "Z07:00"
```

(Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/5xcM0aHsSw)

This is because [RFC3339 expects the timezone offset to be in the format `02:00`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-4.2) with a `:`, but [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) outputs it as `0200`.

So I need to fix this in my C program to output the correct format.

```
 %z     The +hhmm or -hhmm numeric timezone (that is, the hour and
              minute offset from UTC). (SU)
```

## Question

However, now I have a bunch of JSON files with this incorrect format:

```
2016-08-08T21:35:14.052975+0200
```

instead of the correct (with the `:` in the timezone offset):

```
2016-08-08T21:35:14.052975+02:00
```

but I still want to be able to unmarshal it correctly in my Go program. Preferably two different JSON files with only this difference should parse in the exact same way.

Regarding marshaling back to JSON, the correct format should be used.

This is how I have defined it in my `struct`:

```
Time            time.Time `json:"time"`
```

So the question is, what is the "Go" way of doing this?

Also in my code example I am using `RFC3339Nano`. How would I specify that in the metadata for the struct as well? As I have it now with just `json:"time"` will that ignore the nano seconds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json unmarshal time that isn't in RFC 3339 format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087960/json-unmarshal-time-that-isnt-in-rfc-3339-format)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can define your own `time` field type that supports both formats:

```go
type MyTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (self *MyTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    s := string(b)

    // Get rid of the quotes "" around the value.
    // A second option would be to include them
    // in the date format string instead, like so below: 
    //   time.Parse(`"`+time.RFC3339Nano+`"`, s) 
    s = s[1:len(s)-1]

    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, s)
    if err != nil {
        t, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z0700", s)
    }
    self.Time = t
    return
}

type Test struct {
    Time MyTime `json:"time"`
}
```

<kbd>[Try on Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nYESNHgJI8)</kbd>

In the example above we take the predefined format `time.RFC3339Nano`, which is defined like this:

```
RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
```

and remove the `:`

```
"2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z0700"
```

This time format used by `time.Parse` is described here:
https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

Also see the documentation for `time.Parse`
https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse

P.S. The fact that the year `2006` is used in the time format strings is probably because the first version of Golang was released that year.

Answer (score -2):

You can try https://play.golang.org/p/IsUpuTKENg

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z0700", "2016-08-08T21:35:14.052975-0200")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```