# Request body date parsing issue

Tags: json, date, go, go-echo

I have a strange issue. I'm using `echo` package for routing. While I'm decoding `json` to `struct` I'm getting error `parsing time \"\"2019-01-02\"\" as \"\"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\"\": cannot parse \"\"\" as \"T\""`

**my structs**

```
VendorAgreement struct {
    ID                   primitive.ObjectID   `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    StartDate            time.Time            `json:"start_date,date" bson:"start_date"`
    EndDate              time.Time            `json:"end_date,date" bson:"end_date"`
    CommissionPercentage float32              `json:"commission_percentage" bson:"commission_percentage"`
    Status               int                  `json:"status" bson:"status"`
    CreatedDate          time.Time            `json:"created_date" bson:"created_date"`
    Media                VendorAgreementMedia `json:"media" bson:"media"`
}

VendorAgreementMedia struct {
    MediaId     primitive.ObjectID `json:"mediaId" bson:"_id"`
    FileName    string             `json:"file_name" bson:"file_name"`
    SourcePath  string             `json:"source_path" bson:"source_path"`
    CreatedDate time.Time          `json:"created_date" bson:"created_date"`
}
```

**My decoding step**

```
var agreement VendorAgreement
err = json.NewDecoder(c.Request().Body).Decode(&agreement)
```

**request body**

```
 {
    "start_date":"2019-01-02",
    "end_date":"2020-05-06",
    "commission_percentage":10,
    "media":{
        "mediaId":"5cd1644cc57849f0761632b5"
    }
}
```

Comment: you will need a custom json.Unmarshaler to extract the correct time.  There is no way for the default unmarshaler to know your time format. I assume you are `YYYY-MM-DD`, but it could be `YYYY-DD-MM`. json.Unmarshal expects time format `time.RFC3339`

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25088283/1218512) on how to create a CustomTime type to handle custom formats.

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a custom time type in order to unmarshal custom time format:

```
type Datetime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t *Datetime) UnmarshalJSON(input []byte) error {
    strInput := strings.Trim(string(input), `"`)
    newTime, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", strInput)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    t.Time = newTime
    return nil
}

VendorAgreement struct {
    ID                   primitive.ObjectID   `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    StartDate            Datetime             `json:"start_date,date" bson:"start_date"`
    EndDate              Datetime             `json:"end_date,date" bson:"end_date"`
    CommissionPercentage float32              `json:"commission_percentage" bson:"commission_percentage"`
    Status               int                  `json:"status" bson:"status"`
    CreatedDate          Datetime             `json:"created_date" bson:"created_date"`
    Media                VendorAgreementMedia `json:"media" bson:"media"`
}

VendorAgreementMedia struct {
    MediaId     primitive.ObjectID `json:"mediaId" bson:"_id"`
    FileName    string             `json:"file_name" bson:"file_name"`
    SourcePath  string             `json:"source_path" bson:"source_path"`
    CreatedDate Datetime           `json:"created_date" bson:"created_date"`
}
```

Comment: This is working but in my mongo it is saving as `"start_date" : {
                "time" : ISODate("2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z")
            },
            "end_date" : {
                "time" : ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
            },`

Comment: This is so stupid on Google engineers part. No customization whatsoever. No API to pass the format.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse your date returned by mongo like this:

```
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
str := "2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```