# How to parse timestamp with underscores in Golang

Tags: go, timestamp, filebeat

I'm trying to parse access log timestamp like "2020/11/06_18:17:25_455" in Filebeat according to Golang spec.
Here is my test program to verify layout:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    eventDateLayout := "2006/01/02_15:04:05_000"

    eventCheckDate, err := time.Parse(eventDateLayout, "2020/11/06_18:17:25_455")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(eventCheckDate)

}
```

Result:

> 2009/11/10 23:00:00 parsing time "2020/11/06_18:17:25_455" as
> "2006/01/02_15:04:05_000": cannot parse "455" as "_000"

As I understand underscore has a special meaning in Golang, but from documentation it's not clear how to escape it.
Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem possible to use any escape characters for the time layout (e.g. `"\\_"` doesn't work), so one would have to do something different.

[This issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11334) describes the same problem, but it was solved in a very non-general way that doesn't seem to apply to your format.

So your best bet seems to be replacing `_` with something else/stripping it from the string, then using a layout without it. To make sure that the millisecond part ist also parsed, it must be separated with a `.` instead of `_`, then it's recognized as part of the seconds (`05`) format.

```
eventDateLayout := "2006/01/02.15:04:05"

val := strings.Replace("2020/11/06_18:17:25_455", "_", ".", 2)

eventCheckDate, err := time.Parse(eventDateLayout, val)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(eventCheckDate)
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/d64GPBCTMFd)

Comment: OMG, what an awful limitation for such programming lang...Unfortunately it's not a program, but a Filebeat configuration, declared in yml file, so seems it's not possible to replace it...

Comment: If you're using [this package](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3) for decoding your yml file, then you could create a custom type that implements the [`Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Unmarshaler) interface; that way it would be parsed the correct way while unmarshaling. Should be similar to [how it works with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25088283/5728357), except for the names

Comment: No, no, I'm not using Golang at all. It's used by Filebeat https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/processor-timestamp.html

Answer (score 1):

From [time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format)

> A fractional second is represented by adding a period and zeros to the
> end of the seconds section of layout string, as in "15:04:05.000" to
> format a time stamp with millisecond precision.

You cannot specify millisecond precision with an underscore you need `05.000` instead:

```
// eventDateLayout := "2006/01/02_15:04:05_000"  // invalid format
eventDateLayout := "2006/01/02_15:04:05.000"
eventCheckDate, err := time.Parse(eventDateLayout, "2020/11/06_18:17:25.455")
```

So basically use a simple translate function to convert the final `_` to a `.` and use the above parser.

https://play.golang.org/p/POPgXC_qe81