# How to convert Date in Json to normal date to check if it is a leap year in GoLang?

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to convert the date in a json file to normal date in my .go script, i want to check if they are leap years or not, i already did this part, but i want to convert it to date, but i don't know how, i tried to use **strconv.Itoa(users.Users[i].Date)** but it didn't work !

Would appreciate any feedback or help, Thanks !

The error i received when i tried to add both types of date forms at the same time --> **2021/10/21 12:15:35 parsing time "1982/01/08" as "2006-01-02": cannot parse "/01/08" as "-"**

BD.go

```
     package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

// Users struct which contains
// an array of users
type Users struct {
    Users []User `json:"users"`
}

// User struct which contains a name
// a type and a list of social links
type User struct {
    Firstname  string `json:"fname"`
    Secondname string `json:"lname"`
    Date       string `json:"date"`
}

func main() {

    // Open our jsonFile
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("users.json")
    // if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened users.json")
    // defer the closing of our jsonFile so that we can parse it later on
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    // read our opened xmlFile as a byte array.
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    // we initialize our Users array
    var users Users

    // we unmarshal our byteArray which contains our
    // jsonFile's content into 'users' which we defined above
    json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &users)

    // we iterate through every user within our users array and
    // print out the user Type, their name, and their facebook url
    // as just an example
    // write a function to list out the people whose birthday is today.
    // var yr int

    for i := 0; i < len(users.Users); i++ {
        date, err := time.Parse("2006/01/02", users.Users[i].Date)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(date)

        date1, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", users.Users[i].Date)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(date1)

        // check if the date is a leap year, ex: 29 is not a leap year but 28th is !

        if date.Day()%400 == 0 || (date.Day()%4 == 0 && date.Day()%100 != 0) {
            fmt.Println("User First Name: " + users.Users[i].Firstname)
            fmt.Println("User Second Name: " + users.Users[i].Secondname)
            fmt.Println("User Date: " + users.Users[i].Date)
            fmt.Println(users.Users[i].Date, " is a Leap Year ✨✨✨  ")

        } else if date1.Day()%400 == 0 || (date1.Day()%4 == 0 && date1.Day()%100 != 0) {
            fmt.Println("User First Name: " + users.Users[i].Firstname)
            fmt.Println("User Second Name: " + users.Users[i].Secondname)
            fmt.Println("User Date: " + users.Users[i].Date)
            fmt.Println(users.Users[i].Date, " is a Leap Year ✨✨✨  ")

        } else {
            fmt.Println("User First Name: " + users.Users[i].Firstname)
            fmt.Println("User Second Name: " + users.Users[i].Secondname)
            fmt.Println("User Date: " + users.Users[i].Date)
            fmt.Println(users.Users[i].Date, " is Not a Leap Year  ")
        }

    }

}
```

.JSON file

```
{
    "users": [
      {
        "Fname": "Johnny",
        "Lname":"mane",
        "date":"1982/01/08"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Wayne",
        "Lname":"Bruce",
        "date":"1965/01/30"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Gaga",
        "Lname":"Lady",
        "date":"1986/03/28"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "radio",
        "Lname":"head",
        "date":"1988/02/29"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Mario",
        "Lname":"torres",
        "date":"1996/09/28"
      },
      
      {
        "Fname": "robert",
        "Lname":"Alex",
        "date":"1991/12/01"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Julia",
        "Lname":"sevak",
        "date":"1991-03-07" -->

      },
      {
        "Fname": "feb",
        "Lname":"robert",
        "date":"1995-01-31".  ---> 

      }
      


    ]
  }
```

Comment: Check the error from `json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &users)`. You'll see that `"1988/02/29"` cannot be unmarshaled into `int`. So first step you have to do is to change the field type from `int` to `string`. Then, once you've fixed that, you can parse the string using the `time` package. The output of parsing the string with the time package is a value of type `time.Time` which has a `Year` method, use that then to do your leap year logic.

Comment: I changed the type to string like you told me, then i passed the Date in the time.parse in the argument but it returns an error.......... i'm kinda confused tbh, sorry i'm still new with golang! .......here’s a link of what i did so far : https://play.golang.org/p/nwZcOiS0cfR ...

Answer (score 2):

If you unmarshal the date field into a string, you need to parse it with `time.Parse` using a given layout that matches your date format, e.g.:

```
date, err := time.Parse("2006/01/02", users.Users[i].Date)
```

Alternatively, you could unmarshal using `json.UnmarshalJSON` directly into a `time.Time` field, but you would need some additional code to support your custom date format as described in [json unmarshal time that isn't in RFC 3339 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087960/json-unmarshal-time-that-isnt-in-rfc-3339-format).

Comment: Thanks for the help.... if i want to add another alternative to date forms like "2006/01/02" and "2006-01-02" together at the same time, is this possible? Because i tried it but it gave me an error !   i updated my code incase you wanna check it !

Comment: This is another questions, so I would suggest posting it separately.

Comment: @karim Parse first with `"2006/01/02"`, if err is *not* `nil` then parse with `"2006-01-02"`, if err is still *not* `nil`, then fail.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice i already asked this question separately as you have told me, i also added the dates but it's not working ! i updated the code, maybe i'm doing something wrong or so !

Comment: I've added a response to your other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658823/how-can-i-add-two-date-forms-with-time-parse/69658990#69658990

Answer (score 1):

Download the araddon timeparse library from github

https://github.com/araddon/dateparse.git

Below is a sample to format date in golang with this amazing package without worrying about the string date

```
t, err := dateparse.ParseAny("3/1/2014")
```

You can then use the below function to format it.

```
 s:= t.Format("02 Jan 2006")
```

You can definitely try with the above package, it still has some corner cases but works for most of the cases.