# How can i add two date forms with time.Parse?

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to add two different date forms for more flexibility during testing, but I got this error below:

The error I received when I tried to parse dates --> **2021/10/21 12:15:35 parsing time "1982/01/08" as "2006-01-02": cannot parse "/01/08" as "-"**

BD.go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

// Users struct which contains
// an array of users
type Users struct {
    Users []User `json:"users"`
}

// User struct which contains a name
// a type and a list of social links
type User struct {
    Firstname  string `json:"fname"`
    Secondname string `json:"lname"`
    Date       string `json:"date"`
}

func Birthday() {
    // Open our jsonFile
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("users.json")
    // if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened users.json")
    // defer the closing of our jsonFile so that we can parse it later on
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    // read our opened xmlFile as a byte array.
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    // we initialize our Users array
    var users Users

    // we unmarshal our byteArray which contains our
    // jsonFile's content into 'users' which we defined above
    json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &users)

    // we iterate through every user within our users array and
    // print out the user Type, their name, and their facebook url
    // as just an example
    // write a function to list out the people whose birthday is today.
    // var yr int

    for i := 0; i < len(users.Users); i++ {
        date, err := time.Parse("2006/01/02", users.Users[i].Date)
        date1, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", users.Users[i].Date)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(date)

        } else if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(date1)

        } else {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // check if the date is a leap year, ex: 29 is not a leap year but 28th is !

        if date.Day()%400 == 0 || (date.Day()%4 == 0 && date.Day()%100 != 0) {
            fmt.Println("User First Name: " + users.Users[i].Firstname)
            fmt.Println("User Second Name: " + users.Users[i].Secondname)
            fmt.Println("User Date: " + users.Users[i].Date)
            fmt.Println(users.Users[i].Date, " is a Leap Year ✨✨✨  ")

        } else if date1.Day()%400 == 0 || (date1.Day()%4 == 0 && date1.Day()%100 != 0) {
            fmt.Println("User First Name: " + users.Users[i].Firstname)
            fmt.Println("User Second Name: " + users.Users[i].Secondname)
            fmt.Println("User Date: " + users.Users[i].Date)
            fmt.Println(users.Users[i].Date, " is a Leap Year ✨✨✨  ")

        } else {
            fmt.Println("User First Name: " + users.Users[i].Firstname)
            fmt.Println("User Second Name: " + users.Users[i].Secondname)
            fmt.Println("User Date: " + users.Users[i].Date)
            fmt.Println(users.Users[i].Date, " is Not a Leap Year  ")
        }

    }
}

func main() {

    Birthday()

}
```

.JSON file

```
{
    "users": [
      {
        "Fname": "Johnny",
        "Lname":"mane",
        "date":"1982/01/08"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Wayne",
        "Lname":"Bruce",
        "date":"1965/01/30"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Gaga",
        "Lname":"Lady",
        "date":"1986/03/28"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "radio",
        "Lname":"head",
        "date":"1988/02/29"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Mario",
        "Lname":"torres",
        "date":"1996/09/28"
      },
      
      {
        "Fname": "robert",
        "Lname":"Alex",
        "date":"1991/12/01"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Julia",
        "Lname":"sevak",
        "date":"1991-03-07" -->

      },
      {
        "Fname": "feb",
        "Lname":"robert",
        "date":"1995-01-31".  ---> 

      }
      


    ]
  }
```

Comment: It's https://play.golang.org/p/5KC5L42Qi-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error handling seems wrong. You need to check for the error on the first attempt parsing the date. If it failed, try parsing with a different layout:

```
date, err := time.Parse("2006/01/02", users.Users[i].Date)
if err != nil {
  // first attempt failed, so try again...
  date, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02", users.Users[i].Date)
  if err != nil {
     // both attempts failed
  }
}

// all ok
```